# Calculate Percentage From Duration Data in Graphite/Grafana

Tags: time, time-series, monitoring, grafana, graphite

I have state change duration data between my object state in milliseconds.I am sending this data to graphite. I want to create a single stat panel which show me the percentage of the duration less than 20 seconds. How can I create it? Any idea or any similar scenario example will be useful.

```
myProjectName.FromStateToState.duration 10000ms
myProjectName.FromStateToState.duration 15000ms
myProjectName.FromStateToState.duration 21000ms
myProjectName.FromStateToState.duration 25000ms
myProjectName.FromStateToState.duration 30000ms
```

Assume for above scenario I expect my percentage should be %40. Because I have 5 duration data and 2 of them is less than 20 seconds. I am using Graphite as data source and Grafana as visualizing.

## Temporary Solution

Because I couldn't get enough attention and any answer, I will add my temprorary solution to here. If I learn exact solution in the future I will post as an answer too.

Basically I created two counter like counterSuccess and counterFail. If state change duration is less than 20 seconds increase `counterSuccess` otherwise increase `counterFail`. Then get percentage of the success rate via following basic formula `counterSuccess/(counterSuccess + counterFail)`.

**Graphite commands at Grafana Panel:**

```
A : sumSeries(myProjectName.FromStateToState.counterSuccess.count)
B : sumSeries(myProjectName.FromStateToState.counterFail.count)
C : sumSeries(#A, #B)
D : divideSeries(#A,#C)
```

I defined a single stat at grafana to show it as single percentage;

[image: Single Stat Success Ratio]

Comment: Would other TSDBs, with graphite protocol and grafana plugin support, be of interest? Perhaps as an inspiration example?

Comment: We are using Graphite now but prometheus is also used in some projects, so prometheus examples may be helpful too.

Comment: Sorry, no prometheus experience on my end.